# pg_dump: SQL command failed

Tags: postgresql, backup

I am trying to take backup of postgresql 9.0 by using pg_dump command.
command here is:
cd /opt/PostgresPlus/9.0AS/bin and hit the following command

```
pg_dump -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 5432 -U superuser db_name>db_name.dump
```

But i am getting error like,

```
pg_dump: SQL command failed
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  schema "dbms_sql" does not exist
pg_dump: The command was: SET search_path = dbms_sql, pg_catalog
```

please give me suggestion.

Comment: It seems there's custom `search_path` set for the `superuser` user (or the `db_name` DB), which includes nonexistent schema.

Comment: Then what is the solution for that.I am unable to resolve.

Comment: @sharadvishe Check (and probably change) then settings Milen mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

There are [various ways to set the search_path in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777).

To diagnose, log into the same database as the same `superuser` and check:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

If it contains `dbms_sql`, then check your `postgresql.conf`, databse and role settings to find where it came from.

Use any editor or for instance `grep` on in a Linux shell to audit `postgresql.conf`:

```
grep 'search_path' /your/path/to/postgresql.conf
```

To check on database and role settings, use the default command line client `psql` or a graphical GUI like pgAdmin.

In **pgAdmin** you just select the object in the object browser to see all settings in the SQL pane.

In **psql**, use

```
\drds superuser
```

to see settings for this role. And

```
\drds '' db_name
```

to see settings for the database. Or just

```
\drds
```

to see all settings for all roles and databases.